# Cursor moving after remap of <C-e> and <C-y> in vim

Tags: vim

I have encountered some strange behavior in vim. I have done this mapping:

```
execute "set <A-j>=\ej"
execute "set <A-k>=\ek"
noremap <A-j> <C-e> 
noremap <A-k> <C-y>
```

But now when I use `<A-j>` or `<A-k>`, the cursor keeps moving to the right! It doesn't do that when I'm just using `<C-e>` or `<C-y>`.

Is this a bug or some strange feature?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Can you put only the above into a file (plus `set nocompatible` at the top), and try `vim -u settings.vim some-file`? Doing that here, I don't get the "left moving" behavior. Perhaps something else in your vim setup is interacting in an unexpected way.

Comment: I still have the same behavior :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the Vim code you posted:

```
execute "set <A-j>=\ej"
execute "set <A-k>=\ek"
noremap <A-j> <C-e> 
noremap <A-k> <C-y>
```

If you copy/paste it, or if you edit this post (or yours) and go to the end of the `<A-j>` line, you'll find there is a trailing space there. That is significant, because in Vim's normal mode, pressing <kbd>Space</kbd> will move the cursor one position to the right.

Using this code as you pasted it, I can reproduce the problem, although my cursor is moving to the right, not to the left as you describe. The map is executing as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>, which would scroll the viewport downward by one line, and then move the cursor forward by one character.

Your question describes the cursor moving to the **left**, not to to the right. It's possible that you simply confused left and right when you wrote the question, but it's also possible that in your `.vimrc` you have an embedded backspace (`Ctrl-H`, or `Delete`) character at the end of the line. That would have the effect of moving backward (left) by one character, much as <kbd>Space</kbd> advances forward (right) by one character.

Comment: Thanks! I would never have figured that out on my own.
And yes I just mixed up left and right :p